# NullPointerException in Selenium WebDriver Instance When Using in TestNG

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, selenium-webdriver, annotations, testng

I have created a Selenium test suite using TestNG for my website.

The name of my project is Test My Website. In order to execute my Selenium test script and create a test report, I execute the TestNG.xml file directly from the command prompt. For different modules of my website, I have created different Java classes for different modules and have kept them in one package. The source code of my files is given as follows:

**TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Test My Website">
    <test name="My Website Test">
        <packages>
            <package name="testmywebsite" />
        </packages>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**TestLogin.java**

```
public class TestLogin {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    void loginTest() {
        //Code to perform the login test
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void setupWorkHistory() {
        TestModule1.driver = driver;
    }

}
```

**TestModule1.java**

```
public class TestModule1 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    void module1Test() {
        //Code to perform the module 1 test
        driver.getTitle();
    }

    @AfterClass
    public void setupModule2() {
        TestModule2.driver = driver;
    }
}
```

**TestModule2.java**

```
public class TestModule2 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @Test
    void module2Test() {
        //Code to perform the module 2 test
        driver.getTitle();
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.close();
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Note that in the first two Java classes I have added the `setup<Next Class's name>()` method to pass my `driver` instance.

The problem here is that the driver instance gets successfully passed from TestLogin.java to TestModule1.java. However it throws a `NullPointerException` in the `module2Test()` method and hence it shows a failed TestNG report for `module2Test()` despite creating the `setupModule2()` method in TestModule1.java and adding the `@AfterClass` annotation to it.

Can anyone tell me why exactly is this happening here? Replies at the earliest will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Are you under the impression that `TestModule2` runs *after* `TestModule1`?

Comment: Thank you for replying.

Why shouldn't it run if TestModule1 can run after TestLogin?

Comment: Really, I meant to say that `TestModule2` might run before `TestModule1`. That would cause the NPE. Because you have data coupling going on, you might want to create a group dependency that prevents `TestModule2` running before `TestModule1`.

Comment: Seems like a typo mistake. Can you please look at your Test Module Class 2. It is named as "TestModule12" instead of "TestModule2"

Comment: @BobDalgleish It's obvious to me that TestModule2 runs after TestModule1 because the test script of TestModule2 gets executed after TestModule1's.

Comment: @Uday Yes thank you for pointing out the typo, I have rectified it. And no, this typo only existed over here and not in my actual code.

Comment: I found the solution to the problem myself and have posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found a solution to the problem myself.

For that I edited the source code of my TestNG.xml file and my Java class files. They are given as follows:

**TestNG.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<suite name="Test RockON">
    <test name="Rockon Test" allow-return-values="true">
        <classes>
            <class name="testmywebsite.TestLogin" />
            <class name="testmywebsite.TestModule1" />
            <class name="testmywebsite.TestModule2" />
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

**TestLogin.java**

```
public class TestLogin {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    public void setup() {
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test
    void loginTest() {
        //Code to perform the login test
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

}
```

**TestModule1.java**

```
public class TestModule1 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        driver = TestLogin.getDriver();
    }

    @Test
    void module1Test() {
        //Code to perform the module 1 test
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

}
```

**Module2.java**

```
public class TestModule2 {
    public static WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() {
        driver = TestModule1.getDriver();
    }

    @Test
    void module2Test() {
        //Code to perform the module 2 test
    }

    public static WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

}
```

What I did is called the classes individually from my XML file and added the `allow-return-values="true"` attribute to my tests, which allows the classes to allow return types. In my Java classes I instantiated my `WebDriver` instance in every class in a `@BeforeClass` method. Hence I was able to prevent my `WebDriver` instance from throwing a `NullPointerException`.